# Remove empty cells in 2,n cell-array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a cellarray with two columns and several rows.
When I use

```
data = data(~cellfun('isempty', data))
```

It removes the empty cells and creates a cell array with 
both the previous two rows now in one row. I want them to
still be in two rows. How could I do this?

To be clearer:

```
data{i, 1} = subdata_1
data{i, 2} = subdata_2
```

where `subdata_1` and 2 are further cell arrays. 
So the cell array `data` will contain two columns and several rows, 
where each cell is another cell array. Some rows will be empty `[]`
and when I remove these empty cells, `data` will no longer contain
two columns and several rows, but only 1 column. How can I keep the
`N x 2`  structure of the data cell array?

Comment: Your problem is not entirely clear. Please be a bit more specific and try to post an example.

Answer (score 2):

When you remove only one column from a row, the result is going to be a vector rather than a `2 x N` array because MATLAB is unable to determine the dimensionality.

```
a = [1, 2, 3; 4 5 6].';
size(a)
%   3   2

a = a(a ~= 4);
size(a)
%   5   1
```

What you'll want to do instead is to remove entire rows. Now to determine *which* rows depends upon what behavior you expect.

So if we setup some example data:

```
data = {1, 2, []; [], 3, []}.';
%   [1]    []
%   [2]   [3]
%    []    []
```

If you want to remove any row that has an empty cell

```
result = data(~any(cellfun('isempty', data), 2), :);
%   [2]   [3]
```

If you want to remove rows that have all empty cells

```
result = data(~all(cellfun('isempty', data), 2), :);
%   [1]    []
%   [2]   [3]
```